# validation of bootstrap modal form and modal loads after DOM loaded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

before main question i would like to describe my website's files structure for better overview. I have many pages in my website which adds dynamically through my index.php here is code of index.php

```
    <?php
include ('pages/tillBody.php');
include ('pages/navbar.php');
// Set the default name 
$ac = 'default.php'; 
// Specify some disallowed paths 
$disallowed_paths = array('tillBody', 'navbar', 'footer');
if(empty($_GET['ac'])){
$_SESSION["loggedin"] = false;
unset ($_SESSION['userstatus']);
unset ($_SESSION['loggedin']);
unset ($_SESSION["userfn"]);
unset ($_SESSION["userln"]);
unset ($_SESSION["useremail"]);
unset ($_SESSION["id"]);
session_unset();
session_destroy();
}
if (!empty($_GET['ac'])) {
    $q = basename($_GET['ac']); 
    // If it's not a disallowed path, and if the file exists, update $action
    if (!in_array($q, $disallowed_paths) && file_exists("pages/{$q}.php"))
    {
        $ac = $q.".php";
    }
}
// Include $action 
include("pages/$ac"); 

include("pages/footer.php");
?>
```

in my pages folder i have more than 150 pages and some pages has buttons which triggers the bootstrap 3.3.7's modal and in the same page i have half code of modal remaining code comes from php page which i am going to show you later here is code of one of my page which contains button and half code of modal.

```
    <!--button for modal-->
        <button id="<?php if($row['id'] != NULL || trim($row['id']) !=''){echo $row['id'];}?>" type="button" class="btn-verified complaintId" style="color:#000; background: none; border: none;" data-toggle="complaintmodal"> Report</button>
    <!--compalaint modal start-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="complaintModal" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
           <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="cbgoverlay">
             </div>
           </div>
        </div>
   </div>
   <!--compalaint modal ends-->
```

When user clicks the button it trigger the modal and at the same time i run my jquery function to loads the remaining content of the modal through ajax. In my custom.js file i have this code.

```
$('.complaintId').on('click',function(){
    complaintid=(this.id);
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'complaintmodalshow.php',
        data: {id:complaintid},
        success: function(data){
            $(".cbgoverlay").html(data);
            $('#complaintModal').modal({
                show:true
            });
        }
    });
});
```

from here i am loading the modal's remaining code of modal because i need to populate it from database and here is code of complaintmodalshow.php

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['id'])){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    // connection to the Ddatabase
    $servername = "*******";
    $username = "*************";
    try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=*********", $username, "***********");
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $id = trim($id);
    $id = stripslashes($id);
    $id = htmlspecialchars($id);
    $id = (int)$id;
    $query = "SELECT dou.businessName, dou.businessAddress, wp.discount, wp.dealitem, wp.expirydate, 
    wp.description, m.* FROM dineOwnerUser AS dou INNER JOIN webpromo AS wp ON dou.id = wp.ownerid 
    INNER JOIN menu AS m ON dou.id = m.ownerid
    WHERE dou.id = ?";

    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute(array($id));
    $result = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo"<div class='modal-header'>";
    echo"<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'>&times;</button>";
    echo"<h2 class='modal-title text-center' style='color:#8f0000d6'>Report to ".$result['businessAddress']."</h2>";
    echo"</div>";
    echo"<div class='modal-body'>";
    echo"<form id='complaintForm'>";
        echo"<div class='form-group'>";
            echo"<label class='control-label' for='complaintAbout'>Report / Complaint about* :</label>";
            echo"<input type='text' class='form-control' id='complaintAbout' placeholder='Report / Complaint about' name='complaintAbout'>";
            echo"<div class='alert alert-danger hidden' id='complaintAbouterrbox'></div>";
        echo"</div>";
        echo"<div class='form-group'>";
            echo"<label class='control-label' for='complaintDetail'>Report / Complaint detail* :</label>";
            echo"<textarea type='text' rows='5' class='form-control' id='complaintDetail' placeholder='Report / Complaint detail' name='complaintDetail'></textarea>";
            echo"<div class='alert alert-danger hidden' id='complaintDetailerrbox'></div>";
        echo"</div>";
        echo"<div class='form-group'>";
            echo"<label class='control-label' for='complainerEmail'>Your email id* :</label>";
            echo"<input type='email' class='form-control' id='complainerEmail' placeholder='Your email id' name='complainerEmail'>";
            echo"<div class='alert alert-danger hidden' id='complainerEmailerrbox'></div>";
        echo"</div>";
        echo"<div class='form-group'>";
            echo"<div class='g-recaptcha' data-sitekey='**************'></div>";
        echo"</div>";
        echo"<button type='button' id='complaintsubmit' class='btn btn-primary btn-block'>Submit</button>";
    echo"</form>";
    echo"</div>";
    echo"<div class='modal-footer'>";
    echo"<button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>";
    echo"</div>";
}
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
$db = null;
exit;
}
?>
```

I did read a lot answers from this site but i could not find the answer. In my custom.js which is external file, i have my own validation plugin and that works fine with other pages but does not validate this bootstrap modal and i think the reason is that this modal loads after DOM loading or may it is coming from php page that's why it is happening. Can some one help me out how can i validate it from custom.js file because i am not getting any error it seems like this modal does not exist at all however this modal renders perfectly only validation does not work. When i put validation code on same page (complaintmodalshow.php) it works fine. I don't want to do that i want to keep all my js coding in one place. Can some one suggest me better solution?. Here is my validation code just for better overview.

```
"use strict";
$(document).ready(function(){
function showerror(errbox, errcontent){
        if($(errbox).hasClass("hidden")){
            $(errbox).removeClass("hidden");
            $(errbox).html(errcontent);
        }
    }
    function hideerror(errbox, errcontent){
        if(!$(errbox).hasClass("hidden")){
            $(errbox).html(errcontent);
            $(errbox).addClass("hidden");
        }
    }
(function ($){
$.fn.alphanumericspace = function(element, errbox){
var alphanumericspace = /^[a-zA-Z 0-9.,]*$/; /*test, true if matches otherwise false*/
    if(!alphanumericspace.test(element)){
        errcontent = "Only alphabets, numbers, dot, comma are allowed.";
        showerror(errbox, errcontent);
    }
    if(alphanumericspace.test(element)){
        if(element != " " && element.length>0){
            errcontent = "";
            hideerror(errbox, errcontent);
            return "no error";
        }
    }
}
function keepcheckingemail(element, errbox){
var emailfilter = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/; /*test, true if matches otherwise false*/
    $("#email").keyup(function(){
        if(!emailfilter.test(element)){
            errcontent = "invalid email";
            showerror(errbox, errcontent);
        }
        if(emailfilter.test(element)){
            if(element != " " && element.length>0){
                errcontent = "";
                hideerror(errbox, errcontent);
                return "no error";
            }
        }
    });
}
$.fn.emailfil = function(element, errbox){
var emailfilter = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/; /*test, true if matches otherwise false*/
    if(!emailfilter.test(element)){
        errcontent = "invalid email";
        showerror(errbox, errcontent);
        $("#email").focus();
        keepcheckingemail(element);
    }
    if(emailfilter.test(element)){
        if(element != " " && element.length>0){
            errcontent = "";
            hideerror(errbox, errcontent);
            return "no error";
        }
    }
}
}(jQuery));
$("#complaintAbout").keyup(function(){
    alert("complaintAbout");
    complaintAbout = $("#complaintAbout").val();
    errbox = $("#complaintAbouterrbox");
    complaintAbouterr = $(this).alphanumericspace(complaintAbout, errbox);
    if(complaintAbouterr === "no error"){
        complaintAbouterr = "no";
    }
});
$("#complaintDetail").keyup(function(){
    complaintDetail = $("#complaintDetail").val();
    errbox = $("#complaintDetailerrbox");
    complaintDetailerr = $(this).alphanumericspace(complaintDetail, errbox);
    if(complaintDetailerr === "no error"){
        complaintDetailerr = "no";
    }
});
$("#complainerEmail").focusout(function(){
    complainerEmail = $("#complainerEmail").val();
    errbox = $("#complainerEmailerrbox");
    complainerEmailerr = $(this).emailfil(complainerEmail, errbox);
    if(complainerEmailerr === "no error"){
        complainerEmailerr = "no";
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

ok so i have figured it out what was the problem and i am going to answer my own question just in case if some one else is looking for this solution:

**problem:** the problem was my bootstrap modal was loading after the DOM loads because i am using php for this and this modal loads in certain situation as you can see in my question and that's mean my validation plugin loads prior to this modal so the plugin was not able to validate this. To achieve the desired solution i have to give the selector to the jquery which should already be there when js files loads so i changed my function little bit and add one more line which is mentioned below

```
$(".cbgoverlay").on("click", function (){
//old plugin puts inside
});
```

now here is main trick this class **"cbgoverlay"** is already there when my page loads and rest of modal's coding will come later on so when user click on modal this function will run first and after that inside funtion will select the element which renders or loads later on through php page. to understand this logic you have to read my entire question properly. the final solution is here.

```
"use strict";
$(document).ready(function(){
/*complaint modal starts*/
var complaintid, complaintAbout, errbox, complaintAbouterr, errcontent, complaintDetail, robotError, complaintDetailerr;
var complainerEmail, complainerEmailerr, recaptcha;
$('.complaintId').on('click',function(){
    complaintid=(this.id);
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'complaintmodalshow.php',
        data: {id:complaintid},
        success: function(data){
            $(".cbgoverlay").html(data);
            $('#complaintModal').modal({
                show:true
            });
        }
    });
});
function showerror(errbox, errcontent){
        if($(errbox).hasClass("hidden")){
            $(errbox).removeClass("hidden");
            $(errbox).html(errcontent);
        }
    }
    function hideerror(errbox, errcontent){
        if(!$(errbox).hasClass("hidden")){
            $(errbox).html(errcontent);
            $(errbox).addClass("hidden");
        }
    }
(function ($){
$.fn.alphanumericspace = function(element, errbox){
var alphanumericspace = /^[a-zA-Z 0-9.,]*$/; /*test, true if matches otherwise false*/
    if(!alphanumericspace.test(element)){
        errcontent = "Only alphabets, numbers, dot, comma are allowed.";
        showerror(errbox, errcontent);
    }
    if(alphanumericspace.test(element)){
        if(element != " " && element.length>0){
            errcontent = "";
            hideerror(errbox, errcontent);
            return "no error";
        }
    }
}
function keepcheckingemail(element, errbox){
var emailfilter = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/; /*test, true if matches otherwise false*/
    $("#email").keyup(function(){
        if(!emailfilter.test(element)){
            errcontent = "invalid email";
            showerror(errbox, errcontent);
        }
        if(emailfilter.test(element)){
            if(element != " " && element.length>0){
                errcontent = "";
                hideerror(errbox, errcontent);
                return "no error";
            }
        }
    });
}
$.fn.emailfil = function(element, errbox){
var emailfilter = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/; /*test, true if matches otherwise false*/
    if(!emailfilter.test(element)){
        errcontent = "invalid email";
        showerror(errbox, errcontent);
        $("#email").focus();
        keepcheckingemail(element);
    }
    if(emailfilter.test(element)){
        if(element != " " && element.length>0){
            errcontent = "";
            hideerror(errbox, errcontent);
            return "no error";
        }
    }
}
}(jQuery));
$(".cbgoverlay").on("click", function (){
    $("#complaintAbout").keyup(function(){
        complaintAbout = $("#complaintAbout").val();
        errbox = $("#complaintAbouterrbox");
        complaintAbouterr = $(this).alphanumericspace(complaintAbout, errbox);
        if(complaintAbouterr === "no error"){
            complaintAbouterr = "no";
        }
    });
    $("#complaintDetail").keyup(function(){
        complaintDetail = $("#complaintDetail").val();
        errbox = $("#complaintDetailerrbox");
        complaintDetailerr = $(this).alphanumericspace(complaintDetail, errbox);
        if(complaintDetailerr === "no error"){
            complaintDetailerr = "no";
        }
    });
    $("#complainerEmail").focusout(function(){
        complainerEmail = $("#complainerEmail").val();
        errbox = $("#complainerEmailerrbox");
        complainerEmailerr = $(this).emailfil(complainerEmail, errbox);
        if(complainerEmailerr === "no error"){
            complainerEmailerr = "no";
        }
    });
});
/*complaint modal ends*/
});
```

By using this code you will be able to load the modal from php page which is mentioned above in the question and you will be able to validate the form as well.
Good luck. Keep learning.