# html head js files do not apply to dynamic bootstrap modals

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html, pdo

I have multiple php files which are divided into pieces such as tillbody.php has html tag till body tag then i have navbar.php and so on. i am including it in index.php for your better view here is code.

```
<?php
include ('pages/tillBody.php');
include ('pages/navbar.php');
// Set the default name 
$ac = 'default.php'; 
// Specify some disallowed paths 
$disallowed_paths = array('tillBody', 'navbar', 'footer');
if(empty($_GET['ac'])){
$_SESSION["loggedin"] = false;
unset ($_SESSION['userstatus']);
unset ($_SESSION['loggedin']);
unset ($_SESSION["userfn"]);
unset ($_SESSION["userln"]);
unset ($_SESSION["useremail"]);
unset ($_SESSION["id"]);
session_unset();
session_destroy();
}
if (!empty($_GET['ac'])) {
    $q = basename($_GET['ac']); 
    // If it's not a disallowed path, and if the file exists, update $action
    if (!in_array($q, $disallowed_paths) && file_exists("pages/{$q}.php"))
    {
        $ac = $q.".php";
    }
}
// Include $action 
include("pages/$ac"); 

include("pages/footer.php");
?>
```

tillBody.php have all js files including validation. and ac is query parameter i am changing it continuously but all header footer and other php pages remains same. The problem is that some pages have bootstrap modals which comes from server through ajax using **echo** when those modal gets render those js files does not affect it because tillBody loads when site opens and validation does not see the modal's input so validation fails for validate the modals. I know to resolve this issues i need to reloads head section again. can some one help me out how can i solve this problem.
Let say user clicks the button and that button calls the ajax and ajax calls the modal php page and that php page has this modal.

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['id'])){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    // connection to the Ddatabase
    $servername = "*******";
    $username = "*******";
    try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=******", $username, "********");
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $id = trim($id);
    $id = stripslashes($id);
    $id = htmlspecialchars($id);
    $id = (int)$id;
    $query = "SELECT dou.businessName, dou.businessAddress, wp.discount, wp.dealitem, wp.expirydate, 
    wp.description, m.* FROM dineOwnerUser AS dou INNER JOIN webpromo AS wp ON dou.id = wp.ownerid 
    INNER JOIN menu AS m ON dou.id = m.ownerid
    WHERE dou.id = ?";

    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute(array($id));
    $result = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo"<div class='modal-header'>";
    echo"<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'>&times;</button>";
    echo"<h2 class='modal-title text-center' style='color:#8f0000d6'>Report to ".$result['businessAddress']."</h2>";
    echo"</div>";
    echo"<div class='modal-body'>";
    echo"<div class='alert alert-danger hidden' id='robotError'></div>";
    echo"<div class='alert alert-success hidden' id='success'></div>";
    echo"<form id='complaintForm'>";
        echo"<div class='form-group'>";
            echo"<label class='control-label' for='complaintAbout'>Report / Complaint about* :</label>";
            echo"<input type='text' class='form-control' id='complaintAbout' placeholder='Report / Complaint about' name='complaintAbout'>";
            echo"<div class='alert alert-danger hidden' id='complaintAbouterrbox'></div>";
        echo"</div>";
        echo"<div class='form-group'>";
            echo"<label class='control-label' for='complaintDetail'>Report / Complaint detail* :</label>";
            echo"<textarea type='text' rows='5' class='form-control' id='complaintDetail' placeholder='Report / Complaint detail' name='complaintDetail'></textarea>";
            echo"<div class='alert alert-danger hidden' id='complaintDetailerrbox'></div>";
        echo"</div>";
        echo"<div class='form-group'>";
            echo"<label class='control-label' for='complainerEmail'>Your email id* :</label>";
            echo"<input type='email' class='form-control' id='complainerEmail' placeholder='Your email id' name='complainerEmail'>";
            echo"<div class='alert alert-danger hidden' id='complainerEmailerrbox'></div>";
        echo"</div>";
        echo"<div class='form-group'>";
            echo"<div class='g-recaptcha' data-sitekey='6LdZU0QUAAAAABUUQVjOQLbRy6DVMP0kZuOPjg8B'></div>";
        echo"</div>";
        echo"<button type='button' id='complaintsubmit' class='btn btn-primary btn-block'>Submit <span id= $id></span></button>";
    echo"</form>";
    echo"</div>";
    echo"<div class='modal-footer'>";
    echo"<button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>";
    echo"</div>";
}
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
$db = null;
exit;
}
?>
```

again i am repeating please help me out. This modals comes from server after the head tag loaded that's why validation code does not see the input filed so when this modals renders the validation script does not validate this. I am using $(

```
document ).ready(function() {
    validation code;
});//this works for other pages which are already present in DOM when body loads but other pages which comes later from server it does not validate.
```

Comment: can you show a part of `validation code;`?

Comment: Thanks for reply me @kuromoka here i am giving you link of my previous question at the end of question you may find validation code still i use same code.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52490500/validation-of-bootstrap-modal-form-and-modal-loads-after-dom-loaded

Comment: Is your result changed if you try the code like this?
`$(document).on("keyup", "#complaintAbout", function(){`

Comment: @kuromoka thank you so much now it works fine thanks a lot. one more question i have. I have google recaptcha js link on same head section and i have this in modal too the same problem occurs so to solve this i put this <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-*******"></script>. inside modal but it is not appropriate solution. can you tell me how can i reload this js script when modal lauches through ajax from php page?

Comment: you can put answer as answer i will check it as answer so you will gain points :)

Comment: I have just put answer as answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to attach dynamic bootstrap modals, You can use `.on()`.
This method can attach events to DOM that added after page loading.
http://api.jquery.com/on/

Based on [this your codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52490500/validation-of-bootstrap-modal-form-and-modal-loads-after-dom-loaded), you can get expected results as below code.

```
$(document).on("keyup", "#complaintAbout", function(){
    // validation code;
});
```